# How to disable a specific javascript file in Web Browser control in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control

I'm using web browser control in my C# project and I want to disable only a specific javascript file. Is there any way to do that? This script is loading from an external website and I want to disable it.
tx

Comment: Can you please provide a little more information?  Do you want to use the js file only on specific pages or are you loading an external site in your browser control and want to disable a script on the external site, etc?

Answer (score 0):

There's a great article on this at [javascriptKit.com](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml)

Dynamically removing an external JavaScript or CSS file:

To remove an external JavaScript or CSS file from a page, the key is to hunt them down first by traversing the DOM, then call DOM's removeChild() method to do the hit job. A generic approach is to identify an external file to remove based on its file name, though there are certainly other approaches, such as by CSS class name. With that in mind, the below function removes any external JavaScript or CSS file based on the file name entered:

```
 function removejscssfile(filename, filetype){
 var targetelement=(filetype=="js")? "script" : (filetype=="css")? "link" : "none" //determine element type to create nodelist from
 var targetattr=(filetype=="js")? "src" : (filetype=="css")? "href" : "none" //determine corresponding attribute to test for
 var allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement)
 for (var i=allsuspects.length; i>=0; i--){ //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
  if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr)!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(filename)!=-1)
   allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]) //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
 }
}

removejscssfile("somescript.js", "js") //remove all occurences of "somescript.js" on page
removejscssfile("somestyle.css", "css") //remove all occurences "somestyle.css" on page
```